# Couldn't deduce template parameter while using dynamic object created with specified typename

Tags: c++, tree

I have been learning tree data structure for a while. I tried to implement tree using templates. I came up with an error while calling some function for input. This is the fragment where I am getting error.

```
template <typename T> class Tree{
public:
    T data;
    vector<Tree<T>*>children;
    Tree(T data){
        this->data=data;
    }
};
template <typename T> Tree<T>* inputtree(){
    int element;
    cout<<"Enter Root Node"<<endl;
    cin>>element;
    cout<<"Enter Total Number of children of Root :"<<endl;
    Tree<T> * temp=new Tree<T>(element);
    return temp;
}
int main(){
        Tree<int>*root;
        root=inputtree();

}
```

Note: I didn't complete `inputtree()` function completely but still it is not functional without it's content inside it.
I am getting error at line `template <typename T> Tree<T>* inputtree()`.
Why am I getting this error. Is it syntactically wrong or I am making some other mistake.

I tried resolving it by removing the template feature and adding direct as return type. The issue was resolved. However I want my code to be implemented with template.

Comment: The tag [tag:dsa] is used incorrectly. When you pick tags please read their descriptions carefully.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use raw owning pointers. There's also no reason to use a pointer to the `Tree<T>` at all here. Just return it by value.

Comment: Technically it would be possible to make this syntax work when targeting a custom type, if you're willing to let this get a bit ugly by making `inputtree` a function returning a type providing a template that does the actual creation :) ... https://godbolt.org/z/7EracEzzq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputtree` is a function template, not a regular function. All of its template parameters (in this case just `T`) must be given a template argument. Either this argument is provided explicitly, or it is deduced from the function arguments.

In your case, this is not possible:

```cpp
root = inputtree();
```

You are calling `inputtree`, but the compiler has no idea what the `T` is supposed to be. This cannot be inferred from the left hand side of the assignment.

To solve this problem, you would have to call:

```cpp
root = inputtree<int>();
```

This provides the argument `int` for the template type parameter `T` explicitly.

#### Alternative Solution

You could also write a `static` member function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Tree {
public:
    // ...

    // injected class name: Tree refers to Tree<T> here
    static Tree* input() {
        return /* ... */;
    }
}

int main() {
    // using auto, we don't repeat ourselves
    auto root = Tree<int>::input();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JanSchultke for resolving my doubt so quick. Your contribution to stack community is inspiring , keep doing it :)

Comment: Third possibility: `template <class T> void inputtree(Tree<T> &*result); Tree<int> *root; inputtree(root);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm assuming you meant `*&`, the other way around would be ill-formed. I've also considered this option, but it's generally better practice not to create objects and assign them later.

Comment: Oops--yes, a typo. And yes, I tend to agree about initializing objects--but some people prefer this style nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this program on my machine with those includes and it worked just fine

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

don't forget to add the type of the data for your tree
like this

```
 root = inputtree<int>();
```